# Do Smritis mention of any samskaras to be given to a shudra?

Tags: smriti, shudra, samskara

Any purification process (Samskara) is there for the shudras?
Does any smriti tell about purification process for a shudra person?

Comment: Purification process for what purpose? Can you provide some more clarification in the post ,so that it will be easy for the users to write exact answer?

Comment: any sect or religion have diksha.. so can take diksha from a guru whomever you revere.. that is the foremost samskara and do the japa mantra daily. you know konae mantra was given kannakadasa by vyasa thirtha he did japa of that reverential and got aproxa gnana or enligtened its all your belief and faith that make you to the goal of enlightement once enlightened caste is not issue.. then there only 2 types only. one who are enlightened and non enlightened

Comment: Whoever is downvoting, please do mention a reason. This is an excellent question with an excellent answer and doesn’t deserve a downvote in my opinion.

Comment: For example, here if satisfied with Sethuji’s answer, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark (✓) below the voting buttons. And also press up arrow to vote for good answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smritis don't mention any Samskaras for Sudras using Vedic Mantras but leave them free to acquire knowledge from all sources than Vedas.

> A Sudra cannot commit an offence, causing loss of caste and
> he is not worthy to receive the sacraments; he has no right to
> (fulfil) the sacred law (of the Aryans, yet) there is no prohibition
> against (his fulfilling certain portions of) the law. Sudras who are
> desirous to gain merit, and know their duty, commit no sin, but gain
> praise, if they imitate the practice of virtuous men without reciting
> sacred texts. The more a Sudra, keeping himself free from envy,
> imitates the behaviour of the virtuous, the more he gains, without
> being censured, exaltation in this world and the next.(Manu
> 10.126-128)

But he is allowed to do Pancha-Maha Yajnas,Shardhas and worship Devatas without using Vedic Mantras.

> Offering obeisances to the higher sections of society, being always very clean, being free from duplicity, serving one’s master, performing sacrifices without uttering mantras, not stealing, always speaking the truth and giving all protection to the cows and brahmanas— these are the symptoms of the Sudra.(Srimad Bhagavatam 7.11.24)
>
> Service without duplicity to the brāhmaṇas, cows, Devatas and other worshipable personalities, and complete satisfaction with whatever income is obtained in such service, are the natural qualities of śūdras.(Srimad Bhagavatam 11.17.19)
>
> If permission has been given to him, the Sudra may use the syllable
> namah as his mantra. Some people declare that he may himself offer the
> Pakayajnas.(Gautama 10.64-65)
>
> Devoted to his wife, pure, supporting his dependants, devoted to the
> performance of sraddha, he should not omit to perform the fire
> sacrifices with the syllable namaḥ as his mantra.’(Yajnavalkya 1.121)

Laghuvisnu (1.15) contains the dictum that the Sudra is devoid of any samskara. The Mit. on Yāj. III.262 explains the words of Manu IV.80 about vratas in the case of Sudras as applicable only to those śūdras who are not in attendance upon members of the three higher castes and establishes that śūdras can perform vratas (but without homa and muttering of mantras). Aparārka on the same verse (Manu IV.80) explains that the śūdra cannot perform vratas in person, but only through the medium of a brāhmana. The Śūdra-kāmalakara (p.38) holds that śūdras are entitled to perform vratas, fasts, mahādānas and prayaścittas, but without homa and japa. Manu X.127 allows religious śūdras to perform all religious acts which dvijātis perform, provided they do not use Vedic mantras. On the other hand Sankha (as quoted by Viśvarupa on Yāj. I.13) opines that samskaras may be performed for śūdras but without Vedic mantras. Veda-Vyasa (I.17) prescribes that ten saṃskāras (viz. garbhadhāna, pumsavana, sīmantonnayana, jātakarma, nāmakarana, niskramana, anna-prāśana, caula, karnavedha and vivāha) can be performed in the case of śūdras, but without Vedic mantras. Haradatta (on Gautama X.51) quotes a gṛhyakāra to the effect that even in the case of the śūdra the rites of niseka, pumsavana, sīmantonnayana, jatakarma, namakarana, annaprasana and caula are allowed but without Vedic mantras. When Manu prescribes (II.32) that the śūdra should be given a name connected with service, he indicates that the śūdra could perform the ceremony of namakarana. So when Manu (IV.80) states that he deserves no saṃskāra, what he means is that no saṃskāra with Vedic mantras was to be performed in his case.

But Sudras are eligible to take Diksha from other sources like Agamas/Puranas and achive same end result. All such devotees are as respected as Bramhanas.

> I envy no one, nor am I partial to anyone. I am equal to all. But
> whoever renders service unto Me in devotion is a friend, is in Me, and
> I am also a friend to him.(Gita 9.29)
>
> O son of Pṛthā, those who take shelter in Me, though they be of lower
> birth, women, vaiśyas and śūdras can attain the supreme
> destination.(Gita 9.32)
>
> This is the procedure for the ‘dīkṣa’ and its attending ceremonies meant for the Śūdras. This is conducive to the deliverance from the worldly existence for all the four castes.(Varāha Purāṇa 127.32)
>
> They remain severally in their own Varna,Asrama and Acara,but are all impressed (without caste distinction) with the Cakra and Sankha which are sacraments of Vaishnava initiation.(Ishwara Samhita 7.179)
>
> Yogis are born among all castes; and no caste-odium shall hold in their cases, for they have seen their souls.(Bharadvaja-Samhita 1.44)
>
> One who is a devotee of Supreme Personality of Godhead can never be called a Sudra, rather he is glorified as a Bhagavata or one who is connected with Bhagavan. If one is not a devotee of Lord Krsna,however,even if born of a Brahmana, Ksatriya or Vaisya family, he should be considered a Sudra. (Hari Bhakta Vilasa 10.165)
>
> Trying to prove and recognize a Vaishnava devotee through his caste,form,place,home, profession etc is considered as the greatest of the sins. (Prajapathya Smriti)
>
> If a devotee of Vishnu, even though he be a Chandala, is recollected, named, seen or touched accidentally by anybody, O dear madam, the former purifies them. (Varaha Purana 211.9)
>
> It is through deep love that the Chandala makes me his own, while without it the Brahmin is nothing to me. (Garuda Purana 1.231.9)
>
> A Bramhana who is expert in studying all four Vedas is not dear to Me. But a devotee who comes from a family of Chandalas is dear to Me. He should be offered gifts and one should accept gifts from him. He is as worshipable as I am. (Hari-Bhakta-Vilasa 10.127)

Comment: What an answer!. But do you have any idea why Shudras are not allowed upanayanam (since they are not allowed upanayanam they can’t chant Vedic mantras. Even if the other 3 don’t have upanayanam they aren’t really allowed Vedic mantras, they need puranic mantras). So the basic is why are they not allowed upanayanam?

Comment: Thankyou @Archit Ji. My understanding is that Sudras are majority 85% of society and they were Engineers, Metal Works, Potters, Carpenters, Artisans, Craftsmen, Tradesmen, Peasants, Weavers, Cart-builders and other Service Professions . If they stopped all works to build society and study Vedas how will society run? Study of each Veda takes 12 years with lots of restrictions on food, wealth etc. Its tiresome and time consuming and if majority society follows it then building of society shall stop

Comment: @Archit - because upanayana and subsequent rituals require a high level of restrictions and ritual purity, which would be an insane burden to place upon Shudras given the nature of their work and passions. That is correct Sethu - In every company, the workers of the lowest rung form the majority, there are only few Executive Leaders (CEO, CFO, CTO etc.). similarly, majority of any society are shudras, a lesser number are vaishyas, even lesser number kshatriyas, and fewest brahmanas.

Comment: @ram and Sethu ji, thank you. Now suppose their nature of work is such: hair cutting craftsmen hair etc. - maintaining purity of janeu is difficult agreed. Now what happens to a kshatriya (assume there’s a war)? Can he wear the janeu in war because of the bloodshed, the janeu will become impure. Brahmins after doing antyeshti for their yajamaan change their janeu and become pure, on the other hand yes Shudras work is such but then also are Kshatriyas with all the bloodshed involved, or if anyone is misbehaving then whacking them. If he’s a king without bloodshed then ya the Janeu is okay. By t

Comment: @Archit arjuna, yudhishtira etc. all fought in war. blood in war is not considered dirty. janeu getting dirty is not the only criterion. they also have to follow a lot of rules - no meat, no alcohol, no eating before bathing, no eating before puja, no eating in hotels the list is endless.

Comment: Logic, can a Shudra too take it on and change it after he finishes his daily work and he’s released from the burden? 2. Also technically pottery, craftsmen etc are in effect business/ commerce only. How would you divide the line and say okay these are not Vaishyas but Shudras? Yes craftsmen do serve the society, but also Vaishyas with agriculture and commerce. Then how would you say that ha he’s a shudra and not a Vaishya and thus no janeu? 3. How does the nature of work of a craftsmen destroy the ritual purity of the Janeu? Above 3 questions if you could answer it would be really nice please.

Comment: @ram, blood being almost synonymous with death. When you go near a dead body (and the battlefield was filled with dead people) the Janeu must be changed, if you’re not a relative in the sutak category. Obviously blood is gory. How can we say hair (hair cutting shudras, pots) are then dirty? What if you say a shudra will follow those rules of no meat no alcohol etc? Meat is basically bad for all.

Comment: @Archit - blood is dirty during normal circumstances. blood in war is not dirty. Just like killing is bad during normal circumstances, but killing in war is not. if that were the case, they would have to stop the war and do anthyeshti each time a soldier died - but they kept fighting nonstop.

Comment: Stop the war and do antyeshti :D lol! The bloodshed logic is little odd. You’re in the middle of dead bodies. Shudras angle I agree partly except how do you draw the line between a Vaishya and Shudra. And what if a shudra too adhered to not eating meet etc?

Comment: @ram ji Sethuji sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: Good answer! Just to add to the information about the right of Shudras to perform Pakayajnas, in the Brahmana texts, performing certain yajnas was actually mandatory for certain classes of Shudras. For example, Rathakaras were mandated to initiate their Agnihotra in the rainy season, etc. Since in general the Smriti texts are later than the Vedic period, we see a gradual change in them to exclude Shudras from rituals.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RamAbloh Acharya Ji. I am in tears and indebted to you for liking my answer. I am same Srivatsa on Quora. I read your Blogs and answers. You made my day Acharya Ji Thanks a lot. I will surely add it. Even Bhagavatam allows Sudras to do Yajnas and worship Devatas. Let me add.

Comment: Oh nice to see you here as well. Keep up the good work! But please don't call me "Acharya" lol 

Comment: You are indeed my Acharya Ram Ji. You write so wonderfully. When you said Vedanta/Upanishad philosophy is from Vedas and quoted so much I was in tears!You wipe away all my sorrows and motivate me-You are indeed my Acharya. Could you please when free please come on Quora sir and please kindly answer my doubts that I requested in Messenger??

Comment: @Archit - if stopping war and doing anthyeshti was dharma, everyone in kurukshetra would be doing it for 12 days the moment their first soldier relative died at 7am on the first day. But they did not. Which means it is ok to kill/die/touch dead bodies during war.

Comment: @RamAbloh Sir I am really begging you sir! I am dying of dipression. I love Gita and Upanishads but I am loosing my life. Please help me please

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Hello, I'm a little alarmed by your comment. I hope you're not literally serious. I did look at your messages. They are very good, but each of them will take a long discussion :) We need to find a way to discuss.

Comment: @RamAbloh Thanks a lot lot lot sir for the reply! Please sir ! Tell me how to discuss! Quora/Gmail/Facebook/Whatever be the platform, Whatever you say I will do/come  there. I am literally not serious but I am really depressed since many months more than 10! Really need your help! Please tell me what to do! Please don't ignore my message sir! I promise I will make you feel proud for spending your valuable time on me!

Comment: @RamAbloh Sir can we create a room and discuss here itself if and when you are free??

Comment: @RamAbloh Sir I quoted <<Rathakaras were mandated to initiate their Agnihotra in the rainy season>> from Baudayana Grihya Sutras. But Trads replied Rathakaras are exception and according to Manu, all Anuloma Varna(Father Higher Varna and Mother Lower Varna) can undergo Upanayana so there's no change in that. 
Can you please please reply sir. Please dont leave me sir. Please have compassion on me and reply to me please. Please say if in those earlier Times Sudras have had access to Upanayana. Sir Bharadvaja says Sudras can consecrate the 3 sacred fires. Does it proove my point???Please reply!

Comment: @RamAbloh Sir I found in Sushruta Samhita Chapter 2 that Sudra can learn Ayurveda also. "A Shudra student of good character and parentage may be initiated into the mysteries of the Ayurveda by omitting the Mantras enjoined to be recited on such an occasion."
Sir I read Dharmapal Tree you suggested also. But please please please help me if Sudra (Alone by Birth) Have had Upanayana in Earlier times. I did tell few Rishis in Vedic age but Trads said those people were born from Sudra mother and Bramhana father so since father is Bramhana they undergone Upanayana. Please sir help me!

Comment: @RamAbloh Sir Sabara in his Bhasya on Jaimini VI.1.33 where upanayana is denied to Śudras, quotes 'vasante brāhmaṇam upanayīta' as a Vedic text. Arthasastra 2.13.1 includes the sudra among the aryas: arya-prdnam...sudram. Mimamsa-sutra 6.1.27 quotes the opinion of Badari, that Sudras are not precluded from maintaining the sacred fires. I am working very sincerely sir. I think you saw my honesty. Please help me whenever you are free.