# Do Shudras have samsakaras according to smritis?

Tags: caste-system, smriti, shudra, samskara

Do Shudras have samskaras prescribed for them? If yes, how many samskaras can they undergo according smriti and which are they?
Can a shudra go to Gurukula?

Comment: For the Gurukula, yes. You can see the Ram being the friend with a tribe guy. a Tribe guy is not from higher varna. I am a sudra by birth and now I am working with the Iskon. I try to teach people about our religion and yes, we do samskaras to everyone from any varna.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Smritis mention of any samskaras to be given to a shudra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43371/do-smritis-mention-of-any-samskaras-to-be-given-to-a-shudra)